# ggplot2 grey-scale-schemes: suggestions for clarifying changepoint plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, metadata, color-scheme

I can plot multiple simultaneous time series that undergo changepoints and regimes using ggplot2, and I can use colour to make the regimes clear (plotting different sections in different colors using `geom_rect`). I need to produce a plot that makes it clear where the regimes are without the use of color. With three regimes it is possible to distinguish between the regimes using white, black and gray for shading, but it is difficult to tell them apart if more than three regimes are present.

I've put an example of a plot that I can make using color, I'd be very grateful if someone can suggest a plot that conveys the same information without the use of color.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
# generate 3 time series and store them in a data frame
generate_cp_ts <- function(tau, params) {
    ts(c(arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.2), n = tau[1], rand.gen = function(n) params[1] * rnorm(n)), arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.2), n = tau[2] - tau[1], rand.gen = function(n) params[2] * rnorm(n)), arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.2), n = tau[3] - tau[2], rand.gen = function(n) params[3] * rnorm(n)), arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.2), n = tau[4] - tau[3], rand.gen = function(n) params[4] * rnorm(n))))
}
tau <- 100 * (1:4)
ts1 <- generate_cp_ts(tau, c(1.7, 0.3, 1.7, 1.7))
ts2 <- generate_cp_ts(tau, c(0.3, 2, 0.3, 0.9))
ts3 <- generate_cp_ts(tau, c(2, 2, 0.1, 0.7))
tsframe <- data.frame(ts = c(ts1, ts2, ts3), ts_level = factor(paste("Time Series", rep(1:3, each = 400))), time = rep(1:400, 3))
# Work out which colors are needed to color the plot and store in a data frame
CPs <- c(0, tau)
colour.frame <- data.frame(regime.from = rep(CPs[-length(CPs)], each = 3), regime.to = rep(CPs[-1], each = 3), ts_level = factor(paste("Time Series", rep(c(1:3), length(CPs) - 1))), regime = factor(c(0,0,0, 1,1,0, 0,0,1, 0,2,2) + 1))
# Plotting
qplot(x = time, y = ts, data = tsframe, facets = ts_level ~ ., alpha = I(1), geom = "line", ylab = "Time Series", xlab = "Time") +
    geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = regime.from, xmax = regime.to, fill = regime), ymin = -6, ymax = 6, data = colour.frame) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red", "green"), 0.2))
```

[Plot generated by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1MQm.jpg)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1MQm.jpg]

Comment: Try `c("white", "grey", "black")` in place of the existing colors.

Comment: Like I said in the question, white, grey and black work fine for the colors in this plot, but when I am doing a plot with more colors it is really unclear if I use different shades of grey

Comment: I think especially if you have to stay in B/W and have many different areas, there is no way around some text. For example you could plot vertical lines at the changepoints and mid-regime a text stating the regime.

Comment: @David That seems like a good idea, is that easy to code in ggplot2?

Comment: @jeremycg Are you suggesting I use different line types to show the different regimes? I can use the lines to show the changes, but then it gives no indication of the regimes. I guess I could use the lines in conjunction with the regime labels (using `geom_vline` and `geom_text`)

Comment: @Alex, see my answer below, it uses both geom_vline and gives a simple example. You might tweak a bit around, especially you don't need to declare `colour.frame` explicitly, instead you can directly create the necessary parts for `tdf`.

Comment: I tried your sample plot with white/grey/black and it seemed ok to me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Dnm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created `colour.frame` you can insert this code:

```
tdf <- colour.frame

tdf$xval <- (tdf$regime.from + tdf$regime.to)/2
tdf$yval <- max(tsframe$ts) * 0.8 # if 0.8 is higher (0.9) then the text is set higher 

ggplot(tsframe, aes(x = time, y = ts)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(ts_level~.) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = CPs) + # maybe play around with linetype
  geom_text(aes(x = xval, y = yval, label = regime), data = tdf)
```

which gives this plot:
[image: Plot]

Comment: I think this is a neat solution to the problem. I will experiment with the placing of the numbers for the real data I'm applying this method to (some of the segments are very short and that might affect the placement). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Always a pleasure, in the meantime, thank you for giving a syntax for an `arima.sim`, I wanted to look into them, but haven't found the time/opportunity yet. :)